# How to sort column value in mysql when results are grouped

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, inner-query

I have three database tables projects which contains data about projects

Table "*project*":

| project_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | Project 1 |
| 20000 | Project 2 |
| 30000 | Project 3 |
| 40000 | Project 4 |

Table "*revenues*":

| project_id | revenue | fk_setting_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 2000 | 10 |
| 10000 | 3300 | 20 |
| 20000 | 7000 | 10 |
| 30000 | 1000 | 10 |
| 30000 | 15000 | 20 |

Table "*company*":

| setting_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | MARVEL |
| 20 | UNIVER |

Now, I want to sort projects by column value [input = (sort_key = "MARVEL" order_by="DESC/ASC")] for example give me project sorted by "MARVEL"'s revenue DESC such that I get the results in order mentioned below:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 20000 | [{"name": "MARVEL", "revenue": "7000"}] |
| 10000 | [{"name": "MARVEL", "revenue": "2000"},{"name": "UNIVER", "revenue": "3300"}] |
| 30000 | [{"name": "MARVEL", "revenue": "1000"},{"name": "UNIVER", "revenue": "15000"}] |
| 40000 |  |

I'm using this query but don't know how to perform sorting on such models to get desired above mentioned results:

```
SELECT p.project_id, p.name, stid.settings
FROM project p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sid.project_id, 
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(
 JSON_OBJECT(
 'name', sas.name
,'revenue', sid.revenue
) SEPARATOR ',')
,']') AS settings
FROM revenues sid
JOIN company sas ON sas.fk_setting_id = sid.setting_id
GROUP BY sid.project_id) stid ON stid.project_id = p.project_id
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If it's 8.x you can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` instead of `CONCAT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: I'm using 5.7 and it's not supported there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is done by "ORDER BY" is see none in your query.

```
SELECT column1, column 2…
FROM table_name
WHERE [condition]
GROUP BY column1, column2
ORDER BY column1, column2;
```

Comment: How to apply sorting in my query to get desired results which I mentioned above, thats the question.

Comment: the order by for you Zahid might read:
ORDER BY name DESC;
(where name in your example was marvel and DESC is Descending)

Comment: But they want to sort by the Marvel revenue. This is not a single column, it's something derived from the join.

Comment: You can als sort on the fields in the joined table.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Marvel revenue in the subquery, so you can sort by it.

```
SELECT p.project_id, p.name, stid.settings
FROM project p 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sid.project_id, 
        CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'name', sas.name
                    ,'revenue', sid.revenue
                ) SEPARATOR ',')
            ,']') AS settings,
        MAX(CASE WHEN sas.name = 'MARVEL' THEN sid.revenue END) AS marvel_revenue
    FROM revenues sid
    JOIN company sas ON sas.fk_setting_id = sid.setting_id
    GROUP BY sid.project_id
) stid ON stid.project_id = p.project_id
ORDER BY stid.marvel_revenue DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```